# C11 Thread Programming

Tags: c, multithreading, c11

I'm new to C and reading in C11 , is it sufficient to depend on standard C11 threading functions in "thread.h" like cnd_init, cnd_destroy, cnd_signal, cnd_broadcast, cnd_wait, or there are other libraries I shall consider for using threads in server applications.

Comment: sufficient to what purpose?

Comment: server applications :)

Comment: Your question is still way too generic, there is no possible answer.

Comment: You should probably wait for at least one compiler to support C11 threads before targeting it with your code, regardless of the application.

Comment: @Jeff, this is not a question of compilers but of the C library. The musl C library has it, for example, so it comes natively in Alpine Linux, and there are also implementations on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementations of C11 threads are, unfortunately, still pretty uncommon.  You might be interested in [TinyCThread](https://github.com/tinycthread/tinycthread) (disclaimer: I am the maintainer), which is basically a C11-compatible wrapper on top of pthreads and the Windows API.  That lets you start using the C11 API right now, and on platforms where C11 threads are available you can just use that instead of TinyCThread without any code changes.